# Cannot embed youtube video (Cookie Error: samesite attribute)

Tags: html, flask

When I press play on an embedded youtube video I get "Video Unavailable". The Error I am getting in the console is this:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

My HTML code is below:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src={{ embedURL }} frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I have tried a hardcoded embed link as well but it is yielding the same results. Am I missing a property in my tag?

Comment: That seems like an youtube issue. You can use the no-cookie version of youtube which might prevent this error from happening. try `www.youtube-nocookie.com/` instead of `www.youtube.com`;

Comment: @Phiter Just tried to use the nocookie url. Video unavailable once again displays but this time there are no errors in console. Even on the nocookie url the video is unavailable.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/+](http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/+) VideoID.

For instance https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/N4Keb583jf0

Be careful, this is the only URL syntax that is supposed to work all the time : you need www and /embed/...

In your code, embedurl would then be: https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/+VideoID (+ meaning "concatenate")

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO! Try to include more detail around your answer, in order to make it more useful. See [answer].

Comment: this dont work for me